# How to make pod serve load even if container x is crashing

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment with two containers, let's say A and B.

`container A` serves http requests, the important container in the deployment. has liveness and readiness probes properly set.

`Container B` serves as a proxy to a certain third party service through an ssh tunnel, has a very specific usecase, but for whatever reason, the third party service can be unreachable which puts this container on a crash loop.

The question is: How can I make this pod serve requests even if `Container B` is on a crashloop?

TLDR; How to make a deployment serve requests if a specific container is on a crashloop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of can't. You could remove the readiness probe from B but any kind of crash is assumed to be bad. Probably your best bet is to change B so that it doesn't actually crash out to where the kubelet can see it. Like put a little `while true; do theoriginalcommand; sleep 1; done` bash loop on it or something so the kubelet isn't aware of it crashing. Or just make it not crash ...

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling I'd have to do something like that, Thanks